# Batch - Changing wallpaper w/ registry only works if done by the user

Tags: batch-file, registry, wallpaper

So I have an odd issue. I've been creating a batch file that changes the desktop wallpaper periodically via changing the registry key and then refreshing it. The registry key changes just fine, however refreshing it doesn't work. I have to copy the path from the key, then copy it somewhere else (ex. the Chrome omnibox) and then copy that from that place and put it back into the key. After that, if I refresh it, it works perfectly fine.
The code I'm using:

```
@reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0IMGS\16.bmp" /f
```

(changes the path for the Wallpaper key to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Sorted\Coding\Batch\WallpaperManager\IMGS\16.bmp`)

The refresh to apply it:
`RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters`

Does anyone know how to make it work for the batch file?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 Home Ver 1803

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue:
It seems to have been caused by the very small amount of wait that I had between setting the registry key and refreshing the desktop.